# Laravel api paginate how to get next_page_url only

Tags: laravel, pagination

`return Category::paginate(15)
With Laravel how to make paginate api return only`next_page_url
`without`last_page`and`prev_page_url`

I tried `unset($categories->last_page);`

put it dose not work

Comment: You can use `simplePaginate(15)` instead of `paginate(15)` to get rid of the `last_page` and `last_page_url` fields. But removing the `prev_page_url` doesn't seem to be that easy.

Comment: you can get next page url simply by the variable which holding the data and the method nextPageUrl(); 
e.g: $comments->nextPageUrl()